# Task List - Using a custom JS Link file, but keeping original menu options

Tags: 2013, list, task-list, jslink

I have added a 'Task List' app to my site.

Out the box, when you click on the '...' menu option, you see a pop-up with a whole bunch of useful task list related details.

[image]

However, I have also created a custom JS Link file which I have added to the list to do some custom highlighting/logic, etc.

I noticed though that when I add the JS Link file to the list, I now lose those menu details..

[image]

Any idea why, and/or how I can get them back while still using my JS Link file?

Thanks!

I added the JSLink via the 'web part' properties..

[image]

Edit:

Mu custom JS Link file is the following.. (The idea is for it to give each alternating row a different background color, and then to highlight in green the next upcoming due task/project)

```
(function($) {

var statusFieldCtx = {};

statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};

statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = { "MSStatus": {"View": StatusMilestoneViewTemplate}};
statusFieldCtx.OnPostRender = [ rowStyle ];

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);

})();

function rowStyle(ctx){ 
    $(".ms-itmHoverEnabled.ms-itmhover:nth-child(even)").addClass('alternateListRow');
    HighlightNextDue(ctx);  
}

function StatusMilestoneViewTemplate(ctx) {
    var _itemMissed = "Missed"
    var _itemComplete = "Completed";
    var _itemOther = "Missed - Not Complete";
    var _itemValid = "Not Completed";
    var _statusValue = ctx.CurrentItem.MSStatus;
    var _dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.DueDate);
    var _completeDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.CompletedDate);
    var _today = new Date();
    var _title = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;
    var _todayDt = new Date(_today.getFullYear(),_today.getMonth(),_today.getDate());
    var _dueDateDt = new Date(_dueDate.getFullYear(),_dueDate.getMonth(),_dueDate.getDate());
    var _completeDateDt = new Date(_completeDate.getFullYear(),_completeDate.getMonth(),_completeDate.getDate());

    if (_completeDateDt > _dueDateDt)   {
        return _itemMissed;
    }else if (_completeDateDt <= _dueDateDt) {  
        return _itemComplete;
    }else if (_dueDateDt >= _todayDt) {
        return _itemValid;
    }else {
        return _itemOther;  
    }
 }

function HighlightNextDue(ctx){ 

    var AllDates = new Array();
    var AllTitles = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < ctx.ListData.Row.length; ++i) {         

    var listItem = ctx.ListData.Row[i];     
    var today = new Date();
    var today = today.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (today.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + today.getDate()).slice(-2);       
    var _dueDateDt = listItem.RevisedDueDate;
    var _title = listItem.Title;
    var iid = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, listItem);
    var row = document.getElementById(iid);

        if(_dueDateDt >= today){                
            if (row != null){               
                AllDates.push(_dueDateDt);  
                AllTitles.push(_title);                                      
             }                  
        }   
}   

if(AllTitles.length > 0){       
    var listLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-listlink')
    var TitlesAll = AllTitles[0];//AllTitles.reduce(function (a, b) { return a < b ? a : b; });         
    var titleReplaced = TitlesAll.split(' ').join('-');
    for (var i = 0; i < listLinks.length; i++) {
        if (listLinks[i].innerHTML == TitlesAll) {
            var ele = listLinks[i];
            $(ele).closest('tr').attr('id', "Highlight-" + titleReplaced);
            $("tr#Highlight-" + titleReplaced).css('background-color','#F1F8C8');   
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: I may have an idea. Could you please specify how you changed the JS link?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, Added my JS code to post. :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant how you added the JS Link to the "page". Did you set the list view property? the web part one?

Comment: haha, yes. Did so via the 'Edit Web Part' options, on the list view (added screenshot)

Comment: Can you try to change the web part JS Link property so that it look like 'clienttemplates.js|yourOriginalScript' ? as far as I know, task list already include a jsLink to clienttemplates.js and probably now you are overriding it. By using the *undocumented* pipe joiner, you can define multiple jslink file to be used.... so try to include the other script to.

Comment: so in the 'JS Link' field I added `clienttemplates.js|~sitecollection/Style Library/Milestone/MilestoneList.js`. The 'good' news is that it didnt break my custom styling by doing that, but it hasn't added or given me back the original controls yet.. :(

Comment: Ok, I will try to have a look at that as soon as I can. For now, maybe you can doublecheck that that clientTemplates.js doesn't just require the full path (it shouldn't since it is found in the layouts folder, but we are speaking about SharePoint after all).

Comment: heya, so in my JS Link file, I have added this - `SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() { // Start doing my stuff });`, and is fefinitely being called/returned. But not adding the controls, sadly.

Comment: Figured it out, and you were close! :) It wasnt `clienttemplates.js` I was missing, but `hierarchytaskslist.js` ! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. :)

I noticed that when I clicked on the '**...**' I wouldn't get my contextual Task List options, HOWEVER if I clicked on the task in the timeline view, those options were there. Also, once I saw them in the Time Line menu, they then began appearing in my list menu!

So I kept an eye on my js files that were being loaded on my page, and I noticed that a file which appeared after selecting the timeline item was the js file - `hierarchytaskslist.js` ! That was the missing required js file which my custom JS Link file was overriding for my list view.

Did a quick google to find out how to force this file to load, and found two options..

**Solution 1 - Register/load 'hierarchytaskslist.js' in your custom JS Link file**

In my function, I called this.. Which loaded the file when my JS Link file loaded. So my file now starts like this..

```
(function($) {

    RegisterSod('hierarchytaskslist.js', '/_layouts/15/hierarchytaskslist.js');
    LoadSodByKey('hierarchytaskslist.js', null);

    var statusFieldCtx = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = { "MSStatus": {"View": StatusMilestoneViewTemplate}};

    statusFieldCtx.OnPostRender = [ rowStyle ];

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);

})();
```

**Solution 2 - Add it in your list view JS Link field**

Another way to load this file is to add the path alongside your custom JS file in the JS Link field.

`~sitecollection/_layouts/15/hierarchytaskslist.js|~sitecollection/CustomScripts/CustomScript.js`